# Sorting a list that is contained in a sub-class

Tags: c#, list, sorting, google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm trying to sort Chromes Bookmarks in alphabetical order with folders first and then urls

I have these classes (by Mr. Jason Grimme)

```
public class Bookmarks
    {
        public string Checksum { get; set; }
        public Root Roots { get; set; }
        public int Version { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains 'folders' such as 'Bookmarks bar' and 'Other bookmarks'
    /// </summary>
    public class Root
    {
        public RootItem Bookmark_bar { get; set; }
        public RootItem Other { get; set; }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A folder of bookmarks
    /// </summary>
    public class RootItem
    {
        public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
        public string Date_added { get; set; }
        public string Date_modified { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains information about a specific bookmark
    /// </summary>
    public class Child
    {
        public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
        public string date_added { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public Uri Url { get; set; }
    }
```

I using JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize and serialize the JSON file.
The file is deserialized OK into the Bookmarks class structure.

Now I want to sort the the two lists RootItem.Children and Child.Children so that all folders comes first and then the urls all in alphabetical order.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`List.Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx) with a custom Comparison.

This is untested code since I don't have your deserialized structure, you might need to spice it up with some null handling if `Child.ChildItem` can be null.
I also assume that Child.Type tells if the bookmark is a folder or an URL. If not, just change the comparisson `return child1.Type.CompareTo(child2.Type);` to something that sorts by folder/url.

```
public void SortChildren(List<Child> childList)
{
    childList.Sort((child1, child2) =>
    {
        if (child1.Type == child2.Type)
        {
             // Sort by name
             return child1.Name.CompareTo(child2.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            // Sort the type. If this sorts in reverse, swap child1 and child2
            return child1.Type.CompareTo(child2.Type);
        }

    });
    // Sort children recursively
    foreach(var child in childList)
    {
        SortChildren(child.Children);
    }
}
```

Start the sorting with

```
SortChildren(Root.Other.Children);
```

**Edit**
A more simple example of list sorting is

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>{1,5,4,3,2};
myInts.Sort(); // default comparer
myInts.Sort((i1, i2) => { return i2.CompareTo(i1); }); // custom "reverse" comparison
```

Comment: OK, you need to explain a bit more... Where should I put the SortChildren function? And since it doesn't return anything I'm guessing that the original list will be sorted?

Comment: You can put SortChildren in whatever class you like. Yes it will sort the original lists. Check the documentation link at the top.

Comment: Is there a specific part that is hard to understand?

Comment: I'm feeling really stupid right now... As I understand it, In the sample on MSDN you create an IComparer class which has the Compare method which does the compare. Then you call List.Sort() with this comparer. This makes sense to me, but I don't see where your method SortChildren fits in? I would like to be able to have a Bookmarks object and call myBookmarks.Sort(); and get all the List<Child> sorted...

Comment: There are two ways to create a custom sort. 1) Implement IComparer, in this case on `Child`. 2) Create a method that takes two parameters of the type you want to sort and returns an int. I have done no 2 and implemented the method as lambda expression instead of an explicit method.

Comment: You can change `public void SortChildren(List<Child> childList)` to `private` and put it in `Bookmarks`, then you create another method in `Bookmarks`: `public void Sort(){SortChildren(this.Roots.Other.Children);}`.

Comment: Ok, at last I understand! I couldn't get SortChildren to work with the IComparer class... Thank you very much for all your help. The sorting works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

If you want them all in the same list, then you have to create an object with the properties you need, like e.g. MyListItem.

I think referencing `System.Linq;` and then you can do a getter that `select Children.Select(c => new MyListItem( Name = c.Name, etc )`.
You can then do the same for the urls but append `.OrderBy(c => c.Url);`
Finally you can add the last list to the first, using `ToList()` and `Append`.